# Cannot Implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.list<fooClass>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>

Tags: c#, json, generics

I know this question has been asked before but I am unable to find or infer the answer from previous answers.

I am trying to convert a json string into a list using the JSON.net library. I am trying to use a generic list to handle the conversion but it keeps throwing the error of being unable to implicitly convert it.

This is the code that I am trying to execute.

```
public static List<T> Convert<T>(string jsonString, int intCounter)
{
    if (intCounter == 0)
    {
        return (List<fooClass>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<fooClass>>(jsonString);
    }
    else if (intCounter == 1)
    {
        return (List<fooClass1>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<fooClass1>>(jsonString);
    }
    else if (intCounter == 2)
    {
        return (List<fooClass2>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<fooClass2>>(jsonString);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The error is present on each line that invokes the JSON.net.

How do I make the method generic or explicitly convert it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should look like:

```
public static List<T> Convert<T>(string jsonString)
{
    return (List<T>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonString);
}
```

And usage:

```
var result = Convert<fooClass>(jsonString);
```

**upd**

Cannot see any issues, used following code:

```
public class FooClass1
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public int B { get; set; }
}

public class FooClass2
{
    public int C { get; set; }

    public int D { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo1 = "[{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2},{\"a\": 2, \"b\": 3}]";
    var foo2 = "[{\"c\": 1, \"d\": 2},{\"c\": 2, \"d\": 3}]";

    var a = Convert<FooClass1>(foo1);
    var b = Convert<FooClass2>(foo2);
}

public static List<T> Convert<T>(string jsonString)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I originally had but it produced the same error as above so I tried changing things up a little. I want to iterate through them and using the returned list to insert into a db.

Comment: Okay I understand that and your right it does work, but how would I then go about return either 'a' or 'b' because I think that is what is giving me my error?

Comment: @Corey No Idea. As i see in your code you have `if (intCounter == 0)` statements. You can use em on upper level to determine wich class you want to pass to method call as `T`. If you are *sure* that it's right json -> it should work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `(List<fooClass2>)` on each line, use the `.Cast<T>` method, like this:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<fooClass2>>(jsonString).Cast<T>().ToList();
```

This differs in that it casts each object in the list to `T` individually. Casting the entire list to `List<T>` is a different operation altogether.

Comment: Okay that makes sense except now I am getting the error saying that 'an explicit conversion exist, are you missing a cast?' what does this refer to?

Comment: You want to add `.ToList()` at the end as well (`Cast<T>()` returns `IEnumerable<T>`)